# Monotone Convergence Theorem in terms of infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Using the Monotone Convergence Theorem,compute the integral
$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{2-x^2} dm$ expressing the result as an infinite series. Can someone help me in doing this by explaining how to solve this.  I have understood the theorem but how can i apply this? How to express this in form of an infinite series?

Answer:
$\frac{1}{2-x^2} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1-\frac{x^2}{2}} =
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\in N}(\frac{x^2}{2})^n$

Applying MCT, 
$\int_0^1\frac{1}{2-x^2} dm = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{x^2}{2})^n dm\\
=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{[0,1]}\int(\frac{x^2}{2})^n dm\\
=\frac{1}{2}\sum\int_0^1(\frac{x^2}{2})^n dx \\
=\frac{1}{2}\sum\Big[\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2^n .2^{n+1}}\Big]_0^1\
=\sum\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\Big[\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2^n .2^{n+1}}\Big]_0^1\\$

Comment: Hint: rewrite the integrand using a geometric series.

Comment: how to know which series to write it?? we could have written it as an alternating series

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Write $$\frac{1}{2-x^2} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1-\frac{x^2}{2}} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0} \left( \frac{x^2}{2} \right)^n$$ and apply the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: after some steps i arrive at the point $\frac{1}{2}\sum\int_0^1 (\frac{x^2}{2})^n dx $. how to integrate the inside??

Comment: @amreen Do you know how to integrate $\int_0^1 x^k \, dx$? (Here $k \geq 0$ is some fixed number.)

Comment: its not [$\frac{x^k+1}{k+1}]_0^1$

Comment: can u check the ans i hv got $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\sum[\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}]_0^1$ @saz

Comment: Can someone really help in verifying the integration above and help me to do this. It seem silly but am confused.

Comment: @amreen You cannot pull the $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ outside the summation; it should read $$\sum_n \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \left[ \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} \right]_0^1.$$

Comment: ah ok thnks bu t the ans is correct?? pliz confirm

Comment: @amreen Yes, so far it is correct.